# Using a JPanel with a null layout

Tags: java, swing, css-position, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

So I have a class called `CalendarPanel` that extends `JPanel`. It uses a null layout. How would I use `CalendarPanel` as a regular component? When I put it in another `JPanel` and then add it to a window, it disappears. It is only visible when I add it directly to a window.

EDIT:
And yes, I realize using a `JPanel` with a null layout is bad practice. `CalendarPanel` is actually someone else's code, and I'm trying to use it for my purposes without having to refactor it.

Comment: *"Using a JPanel with a null layout"*  ***Doooooooooooon't!***

Comment: *"..CalendarPanel that extends JPanel"*  Why?  Or rather, why not simply use an instance of a panel?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, Why not make a class that extends JPanel? I'm making a rather large application, so I'm creating different classes for the various GUI components so as to stay somewhat organized.

Comment: *"stay somewhat organized"*  I don't see the connection.  I could create a class for a `CalendarComponent` that does not explicitly extend anything, with a `getGui()` method that creates and returns a `JComponent` (that might be a `JPanel` or other things).  In general, see [inheritance vs composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Now I understand what you were saying. As mentioned in my edit above, it's not my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It is only visible when I add it directly to a window.

That is because a window uses a BorderLayout by default and will automatically resize the panel to fit in the window.

> When I put it in another JPanel and then add it to a window, it disappears.

The is because a JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default and a flow layout respects the preferred size of the components added to it. Since you are using a null layout your panel doesn't have a preferred size so nothing gets painted.

That is why you should NOT use null layout. Instead use layout managers because they do all this extra work for you.

Comment: So is there any workaround to get it to appear in another JPanel?

Comment: Use layout managers since they will determine the preferred size for you. If you don't use a layout manager then you are responsible for overriding the getPreferredSize() method to return the size of your panel.

Comment: That doesn't sound too awful.

Comment: Have you read all the comments??? Everybody recommends using a layout manager because calculating the preferred size of a panel is not easy which is why everybody else lets the layout manager do its job. Sure you can pick random numbers like (200, 200), but that doesn't mean anything and you will get an ugly GUI that is not easy to change.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE**: it is a very bad idea in general to use a null layout.  Use a `LayoutManager` instead.

If you insist on using a null layout, you're going to have to position the `JPanel` manually as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).  Here's an example.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {
   static int defaultX = 10;
   static int defaultY = 10;
   static int defaultW = 150;
   static int defaultH = 50;

   public Test() {
      super("Test");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      // here is the outer JPanel
      final JPanel outer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      JPanel inner = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      // here is the main component we want to see
      // when the outer panel is added to the null layout
      JButton mainComponent = new JButton("Test");
      inner.add("Center", mainComponent);
      outer.add("Center", inner);

      JPanel c = (JPanel)getContentPane();

      // This panel has a null layout!
      final JPanel nullLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
      nullLayoutPanel.setLayout(null);
      c.add("Center", nullLayoutPanel);

      // set the bounds of the outer panel manually
      // when using the null layout!
      nullLayoutPanel.add(outer);
      outer.setBounds(defaultX, defaultY, defaultW, defaultH);

      JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
      final JTextField x = new JTextField(""+defaultX, 3);
      final JTextField y = new JTextField(""+defaultY, 3);
      final JTextField w = new JTextField(""+defaultW, 3);
      final JTextField h = new JTextField(""+defaultH, 3);
      JButton b = new JButton("Resize");
      b.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               try {
                  outer.setBounds(
                        Integer.parseInt(x.getText()),
                        Integer.parseInt(y.getText()),
                        Integer.parseInt(w.getText()),
                        Integer.parseInt(h.getText())
                  );
                  outer.revalidate();
               } catch(Exception ex) {}
            }
         }
      );
      controlPanel.add(x);
      controlPanel.add(y);
      controlPanel.add(w);
      controlPanel.add(h);
      controlPanel.add(b);
      c.add("South", controlPanel);
   }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             Test p = new Test();
             p.setSize(300, 200);
             p.setVisible(true);
          }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why?  Using a null layout may not be best practice, but it certainly is an option.  Did you read my link to the official Java documentation regarding this?

Comment: it's an option only for developers with a extreme masochistic stroke ;-) Not everything that's doable should be done, especially not if there's not the very rare odd corner case requiring extreme measures. This context is not.

Comment: Yes, but why does this answer merit a -1?  What is technically wrong with it, aside from the fact that most developer's don't like null layout?

Comment: it's technically wrong to advice using a null layout if it's not required

Comment: I didn't advise it, I straightforwardly answered the OP's question.  Would it help if I add a disclaimer that this is a bad idea in general?

Comment: yeah, it certainly would help to add a **strong** disclaimer :-)