# ImageLabel not shown in BorderLayout.NORTH - Java Swing

Tags: java, image, label, panel, jlabel

So, I have this BorderLayout frame with a panel pnlLogo in North. In that panel I've got an image in a label. The problem is: I want to put it in the left upper corner of that north. But when I setLayout(null) and setbounds, the image doesn't show at all. In the normal flowlayout it does showup. Anyone who knows why?

```
package panels.components;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Logo extends JPanel{
// Declareren
public JLabel lblLogo;

public Logo(){
    // Layout
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setBackground(Color.decode("#414141"));

    // Logo -> Label
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("src/media/Logo.jpg");
    lblLogo = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);

    // Bounds
    lblLogo.setBounds(10, 10, 210, 84);

    // Panel
    this.add(lblLogo);

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a JPanel with a null layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982781/using-a-jpanel-with-a-null-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don´t you want to use a layout for the panel?
If you don´t want the image to fill out the whole frame, you can use

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 80));
```

Make sure you don´t use the absolute layout (setLayout(null)) when using this. 
Here is a helpful side: [click!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html)